# Javascript - .split with Regex to Return All Matches If Next Character Is Not

Tags: javascript, regex

Using `.split()` with Regex, what is the proper way to perform a split with using whitespace with multiple characters?

For example, with a string like:

`const str = 'Supreme > 22 < 27 < 34> 185';`

the expected outcome would be:

`const output = ['Supreme', '> 22', '< 27', '< 34', '> 185'];`

I have attempted using `.split()` with the pattern `/.+?(?=>|<)/`, but it returns the opposite like:

`const opposite = [ '', '', '', '', '> 185' ]`

Comment: Use `str.split(/\s*(?=[><])/).filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\s*(?=[><])/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zAdjku/1). It matches:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(?=[><])` - immediately followed with `<` or `>`.

Since the pattern can match empty strings, there will be empty items in the resulting array, that will need removing, e.g. with `.filter(Boolean)`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const str = 'Supreme > 22 < 27 < 34> 185';
console.log(str.split(/\s*(?=[><])/).filter(Boolean));
```

A matching approach can be implemented using

```js
console.log('Supreme > 22 < 27 < 34> 185'
   .match(/(?:^|[<>])[\s\S]*?[^\s<>](?=\s*[<>]|$)/g))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zAdjku/3). Details:

- `(?:^|[<>])` - start of string or `<` or `>`
- `[\s\S]*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `[^\s<>]` - any char but a whitespace, `>` and `<`
- `(?=\s*[<>]|$)` - immediately followed with any 0+ whitespace chars and then `<` or `>` or end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use match method. It will return your expected output.

```js
const str = 'Supreme > 22 < 27 < 34> 185';
const ret = str.match(/(\w+)|(<\s*\d+)|(>\s*\d+)/g);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: You can omit the capturing groups, and omit 1 of the alternatives using a character class `<>`. The pattern can be shortened to `\w+|[<>]\s*\d+`